# How to handle socketIO when app is not running

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been doing alot of testing with socketIO and have got stuck with handling situations where my node app is simply offline. The documentation provides no real insight into this issue.

So if i run my website and node app is simply not running, console.log gives:

`GET http://[url]:[port]/socket.io/socket.io.js`

`Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined`

This is hardly surprising, how ever what i don't understand is how to handle these errors and simply have the script try to attempt a reconnect until it finally does reconnect (if ever).

My script looks like this:

```
<script src="http://[url]:[port]/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  windows.onload = function()
  {
        socketio = io.connect("http://[url]:[port]");

        socketio.on('connecting', function() {
                 console.log('trying to connect');
        });             

        socketio.on('connect', function() {
                   console.log('connected');
        });     
  }
</script>
```

Is there a way to handle this kind of problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the server is offline, your initial `<script>` tag to load the Socket.io client library fails, so you never get the `io` object in the first place.

To retry, you can add a new `<script>` tag to load the same URL again and see if it succeeds.

Better yet, copy the socket.io client library to the server hosting your HTML, so that the script will always load.  You can then simply handle connection errors from `io.connect()`.

Comment: If i add a new <script> won't I have two of them in the page source? I  would have to remove the original one first right?

Comment: @Dave You are correct that two `<script>` elements will exist in the DOM, but if the first has already produced an `error` message, its life cycle (as it were) is finished. It's not ever going to load the script, because it gave up when it failed the first time.

Comment: I just noticed this causes app.js to throw an error for some reason if you copy the client library

Comment: @SLaks Don't worry the error was my fault ! But i do have one problem! If io.connect cannot connect to the server (because its down) - i don't know how to check that? I could not find information on what to check against to know if connection to the server was made.

Comment: @Dave: Try handling `connect_failed`

Comment: Yeh it works now ! Finally covered all eventualities :D

Answer (score 0):

There are a few events that you can bind to.

```
socket.on("connect_failed", function() {
   // Do whatever you wanted to do on failure
});
```

For a full list of exposed events check here: [exposed socket.io events](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Exposed-events)

**Edit**

Ah, I'm sorry.  I misunderstood your question.  I thought you wanted to handle when the socket server was offline.  If you want to handle not being able to get at the socket.io client script, maybe you could check if `socket` is null or undefined and handle thought that.  Then also fire a `setTimeout` function to try and load the script asynchronously after a wait period and then check if `socket` is still undefined or null.  Or, as the other answer suggests, pack the socket.io client library with the rest of your HTML page.

Comment: If the node app is not running i do not believe it will receive `connect_failed` in the first place..

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry.  I misunderstood your question.  You're right, you don't have a `socket` to call events on to begin with.  As the other answer says, it would be a better idea to pack the client library with the HTML page.